# Node.js specify tls connect timeout

Tags: node.js, ssl, timeout

How can I specify timeout for an tls.connect() call?
I know there is handshakeTimeout for server, is there something similar for client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to call [tlssock.setTimeout()](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/4a2792cd2f86403a71edf65d82600b6aad5713bf/lib/tls.js#L549-L551) which calls the underlying [socket.setTimeout()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.26/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback). `socket.setTimeout()` is the same mechanism that the TLS server uses for the [handshakeTimeout](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/4a2792cd2f86403a71edf65d82600b6aad5713bf/lib/tls.js#L1174-L1176).

Comment: It worked after I added this in timeout handler socket.emit('error', new Error('Handshake timeout'));